# Work with multiple profiles in provider.tf without swapping environment variables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, environment-variables, terraform

I use Terraform v0.13.5 to provision resources for multiple projects using multiple profiles.

I have the following declared in `provider.tf`:

```
shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
profile = "profile_name"
```

But I get the error:

> Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: no valid credential sources for Terraform AWS Provider found.

It works if I use shell environment variables:

```
export AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=/Users/$USER/.aws/credentials
export AWS_PROFILE=profile_name
```

It seems that both the environment variables and the info in the provider file are required. If there's a mismatch between the two, Terraform errors out.

I can add the environment variables to `.bashrc` but it's a pain since I have multiple profile names for different projects.

How can I use multiple profiles and specify them only in the `terraform.tf` file?

Comment: The environment variables are common to both the AWS provider and the S3 state storage backend, so if you _aren't_ using the environment variables you'll need to set these arguments in at least two places in your configuration. From what you've shared it sounds like you've only configured the provider, and not the S3 backend.

Answer (score 1):

Martin's comment is correct.

I needed to also add my profile name to the terraform.tf file as well as the provider.tf file.

I did following and it worked.

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
  bucket  = "my_bucketname"
  key     = "my_keyname"
  region  = "us-west-1"
  profile = "my_profile_name"
  }
}
```